# Check all tables in a schema for X fields?

Tags: sql-server

I want to make sure that all of the tables in my schema have fields named "updateddate" and "createddate". Obviously, I could check them manually, but how can I generate a list of tables that are missing these fields? Even better, how can I use the resulting list and generate the SQL needed to create the missing column for that table?

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @sch SYSNAME = N'my_schema_name';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@sch) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + ' ADD createddate DATETIME
      NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE();' 
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.name = @sch
AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
      AND name = N'createddate'
  );

SELECT @sql += N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@sch) +'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + ' ADD updateddate DATETIME;' 
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.name = @sch
AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
      AND name = N'updateddate'
  );

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

To automate this a little further, you can use a table variable or #temp table (no such thing as an array in SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @cols TABLE
(
  col SYSNAME, 
  ctype SYSNAME,
  def SYSNAME
);

INSERT @cols(col,ctype,def) VALUES
(N'createddate', N'DATETIME', N'NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()'),
(N'updateddate', N'DATETIME', N'NULL'),
(N'somethingelse', N'VARCHAR(32)', N'');

DECLARE @sch SYSNAME = N'my_schema_name';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@sch) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + ' ADD ' + QUOTENAME(cols.col) + ' ' + cols.ctype 
  + ' ' + cols.def + ';' 
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
CROSS JOIN @cols AS cols
WHERE s.name = @sch
AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
      AND name = cols.col
  );

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that in both cases above, depending on the number of tables that don't have these columns, `PRINT` might truncate the output it shows you, but this is due to an inherent 8K limitation of `PRINT` (or less data depending on your settings in SSMS). I can assure you the command it will execute doesn't end abruptly like that.

Comment: Thank you! I see that the code snippets are similar, makes sense. Is there a way to have the new field names in some sort of array (or temp table???) and then script against that?

Comment: @JimBeam sure, but how much is that really going to help you? After all, you do need to do one thing for created date (use a default), and probably something different for updated date (set it via trigger or something).

Comment: I see your point. But the names were just placeholders in my example - I cant reveal the actual names. So what if I have a list of X columns to add? Can I use an array?